# The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "featured"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Stack Trace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "featured".]
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.VerifyRenderedBodyOrSections() +192327
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +316
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +95
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +233
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +71
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +246
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +95
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +295
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9658396
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to include **

> "@RenderSection("featured", required: false)"

** in the header section of the _layout.cshtml

Comment: worked for me.  I'm surprised required:false isn't the default setting for _layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 9):

It means that you have defined a section in your master ***Layout.cshtml***, but you have not included anything for that section in your View.

If your `_Layout.cshtml` has something like this:

```
@RenderSection("scripts")
```

Then all Views that use that Layout must include a `@section` with the same name (even if the contents of the section are empty):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section scripts{
    // Add something here
}
```

> As an alternative, you can set required to false, then you won't be
>   required to add the section in every View,

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

or also you can wrap the `@RenderSection` in an if block,

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("scripts"))
{
    RenderSection("scripts");
}
```

Also, you can add the following line to the `_Layout.cshtml` or _`Layout.Mobile.cshtml`:

> @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Answer (score 1):

In view if you use @section scripts {} or @section styles {} you must add the below code in header or Body in **layout page**
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
 @RenderSection("styles", required: false)

Answer (score 0):

This error can be raised also when you set Layout property of the `_Layout.cshtml` file to itself. For example via the following code in the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```